# SQL Syntax Help on Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where i would like to pull of the users who have not made a pick for this weeks tournament and sent them an email reminder. I have the following query, but it is not displaying any results. It should be giving me all 11 users as this tournament is next week.

```
SELECT 
T1.username, 
T2.*
FROM 
(SELECT 
    id, 
    lead_id, 
    form_id, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 1 then value end) username, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) email, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 6 then value end) tournament_name, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 3 then value end) primary_golfer, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 4 then value end) backup_golfer, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 5 then value end) date, 
    MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) tournament_id 
FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail` 
GROUP BY lead_id 
HAVING tournament_id = '4867aac6-186a-4508-9c57-69a468e1167f')T1 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT user_login, user_email FROM wp_users)T2 ON T1.username = T2.user_login
```

Comment: [Can you provide the sql fiddle of your tables with sample dataset](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I would suggest you go to SQLFiddle, load up your schema, put in some sample data and show what you need for a result set.

Comment: Here is the SQL fiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9649c/1 as you can see it produces no results. If you take the tournament ID from the tournament list on the left, it will produce the results I am looking for

Comment: I'm hoping the emails you posted in your SQLFiddle are not real email addresses.

Comment: oh they were real alright, just updated it

Comment: Be cautious not to post real information. Test data suffices.

Comment: @hosker your `HAVING tournament_id` clause is filtering results because you don't have *4867aac6-186a-4508-9c57-69a468e1167f tournament id* present in `wp_rg_lead_detail` table so therefore you are not getting any results [**see here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9649c/3)

Comment: and if I remove it, I get the following results

    username    user_login    user_email
    hosker      hosker         email@address.com
    hosker      tricky         email@address.com
 and this contiunes for each user in the table

Comment: yes you will have these results without the condition so i guess if this is what you need then from wp_rg_lead_detail you should select only username for better performance

Comment: but if you look at the top of the sql query, I am only grabbing the username

Comment: @hosker i hope [**this fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9649c/5) will clear my previous comment to select only the username field

Comment: I understand your comment about selecting only the username. I guess I am not making myself clear here. I have a list of weekly picks from 11 users. Each week picks are made. The query I am using takes each value that is on a separate line and combines it into one that I can work with easier. I need to have this whole statement and I need to filter is by tournament_id for the upcoming tournament that week. I want to select all users who have not made a pick for the tournament that week to receive and email.

Comment: would a NOT IN statement be a possibility?

Comment: For a start, you should be grouping by ALL these things (id,lead_id,form_id). I cannot see that anything else makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic started out wrong. You probably need to start with all players, then associate them with tournaments. Using the LEFT JOIN and the WHERE clause's IS NULL finds those users without a tournament entry.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.*
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lead_id
                , MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) AS email
                , MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) AS tournament_id
           FROM wp_rg_lead_detail
           GROUP BY lead_id
          ) AS t1
  ON t1.email = wp_users.user_email
    AND t1.tournament_id = '4867aac6-186a-4508-9c57-69a468e1167f'
WHERE t1.lead_id IS NULL;
```